# FillRect doesn't work in some case

Tags: c++, c, winapi, user-interface, window

in my code:

```
void Surface::paintBorders(const Color& color, int borderWidth){
HBRUSH colorBrush = CreateSolidBrush(color.getRGB());
RECT border;

//Top Border:
border.top = 0;
border.bottom = borderWidth;
border.left = 0;
border.right = mRect.right - mRect.left;
FillRect(mHDC, &border, colorBrush);

//Bottom border
border.top = mRect.bottom - mRect.top - borderWidth;
border.bottom = mRect.bottom - mRect.top;
border.left = 0;
border.right = mRect.right - mRect.left;
FillRect(mHDC, &border, colorBrush);

//Right border
border.top = 0;
border.bottom = mRect.bottom - mRect.top;
border.left = mRect.right - mRect.left - borderWidth;
border.right = mRect.right - mRect.left;
FillRect(mHDC, &border, colorBrush);

//Left border
border.top = 0;
border.bottom = mRect.bottom - mRect.top;
border.left = 0;
border.right = borderWidth;
FillRect(mHDC, &border, colorBrush);

DeleteObject(colorBrush);
```

}

only the top and the left borders are being painted , with the bottom and the right aren't.
I quote from MSDN:

> This function includes the left and top borders, but excludes the right and bottom borders of the rectangle.

I don't know if it's related or not .
I know for sure that all the coordinations are OK, also the HDC and HBRUSH parameters. 
any ideas?

Comment: It is obvious that your calculations is a bit off. Try to move the right, bottom borders to the left and top.

Comment: You showed part of the code only. We can only guess at the specifics. Why not show a complete program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys, I got the answer , apparently rect was retrieved by GetWindowRect instead GetClientRect which messed up all of the coordinations

Comment: You should delete the question. There's no value for future visitors and nothing in the question talks about GetWindowRect  or GetClientRect.